# Can't install ios-deploy

Tags: cordova

Having an issue setting up my Cordova environment on a Mac. I am currently attempting to install ios-deploy. This is what happens. How can I get it installed?

```
npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.9.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.9.0 ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: have you tried with `sudo npm i -g ios-deploy`?

Comment: Same problem here, sudo nom i -g ios-deploy does not work too

Answer (score 7):

This was answered in this [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213400/npm-ios-deploy-install-issues):

```
If you have OS X 10.11 El Capitan or greater, then execute the npm     
command with the --unsafe-perm flag, and then it should work:

npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```