# npm iOS-deploy install issues

Tags: npm

npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.9.1~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.9.1 ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

This is the error message that I am getting any help would be great thanks

Comment: answered my own question thanks

Comment: how'd you end up solving it?

Answer (score 12):

If you have OS X 10.11 El Capitan or greater, then execute the npm command with the **--unsafe-perm** flag, and then it should work:

`npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true`

Comment: Note for M1 machines: @SaWo's answer didn't work for me because I was running the terminal under Rosetta 2, after running the same command on normal terminal it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This may help you...

**npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true**

```
               or
```

**npm install -g ios-deploy --allow-root**

Answer (score 2):

If you have previously installed ios-deploy via npm, uninstall it by running:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ios-deploy
```

Install ios-deploy via Homebrew by running:

```
brew install ios-deploy
```